# Why does age of a water filter affect how to kasher it?

Tags: time, chametz-leaven, kashering-kosherization

[The Star-K Web site](http://www.star-k.org/kashrus/kk-passover-kashering.htm) says about water filters:

> If they are metal and have been on [the faucet] consistently since the previous Pesach, they should be left on during kashering of the spigot [for Pesach]. If they were first attached some time after Pesach, they should be removed before kashering the spigot, and should be kashered separately.

Why does when the filter was attached matter?

Answer (score 3):

If the filter was attached after the previous Pesach, some chametz might have gotten on the spigot before the filter was attached.  If it had been on since the previous Pesach, the spigot itself would not have been exposed to chametz, so there is no need to remove the filter to kasher it.

Comment: Seems reasonable enough